# Segmentation Fault reason unknown Opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, segmentation-fault

I have the following code compiled in linux terminal (c++ in linux) and am using OpenCv 2.4.3.

However, am getting a segmentation fault in run time and I really have no clue as to why. I have placed differnt cout statements to know if the program processed to the particular stage but in vain. Could you please help me? Please explain me what exactly is this segmentation fault. Am stuck here for a long time.

```c
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{           
    cout<<"check"<<flush;
    Mat src,src_gray,dst;
    int kernel_size = 3;
    int scale = 1;
    int delta = 0;
    int ddepth = CV_16S;
    char* window_name = "sharpness estimate";

    int freq,rows,cols =0;
    double *estimate,*min = 0;
    Point *minLoc,*maxLoc = 0;
    src = imread("/home/siddarth/examplescv/erez images/image53.jpg");
    if( !src.data )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow(window_name,CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Mat abs_dst;
    cvtColor(src,src_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    Laplacian(src_gray,dst,ddepth,kernel_size,scale,delta,BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(dst, abs_dst);

    minMaxLoc(dst,min,estimate,minLoc,maxLoc,noArray());
    Size s = dst.size();
    rows = s.height;
    cols = s.width;
    cout<<rows<<endl<<cols<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=cols;j++)
        {
            if(dst.at<double>(i,j) >= *estimate-100
               && dst.at<double>(i,j) <= *estimate+100)
            {
                cout<<freq++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"estimate :"<<*estimate<<endl;
    cout<<"frequency :"<<freq<<endl;
    imshow(window_name,abs_dst);
    waitKey(1000);
    return 0;   
 }
```

The code doesn't cross the first "check" print statement just after the main function declaration. That is the confusing issue. But once I flushed the first print statement, it got executed. I am still facing issues.

Comment: So what did your `cout`s tell you? There's a lot missing here. We really need to know more about when it occurs.

Comment: cout is giving me nothing. that's the whole confusion. The initial check is also not reached. Please help me.

Comment: If you add an "endl" to your first cout, I bet that one prints, and it fails a few lines later. Try adding more cout or run your code in a debugger. It's most likely obvious!

Comment: Just a note for future readers: the *flushing* wouldn't have been a requirement if **[cerr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr)** was used which is generally synced with stdio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you insert `std::endl` into `cout` so that the buffer is flushed. This will probably be why you're not seeing any output.

One immediate issue is that your `for` loops check the condition with `<=`, meaning that you're probably going one past the end. But since you're using `at`, you should have an exception thrown (assuming this `Mat` type acts like a standard container).

Also, you're creating lots of pointers to pass as some function arguments (for example, `double* estimate`). This doesn't actually give you a `double` object though, just a pointer. Unless the function you're passing them to is allocating a `double` for you (which I hope it's not), you're doing it wrong. You should be doing:

```
double estimate;
minMaxLoc(/* ... */, &estimate, /* ... */);
```

You'll need to do that with all of the values you're getting through output parameters.

Another thing to note: Doing `int i, j = 0;` only initialises `j` to `0`, but not `i`. You need to do `int i = 0, j = 0;`.

---

Okay, I'm going to explain why fixing the initialisers works. I had to look up [the definition of minMaxLoc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmaxloc#minmaxloc) to see what happens. Basically, the function is something like the following:

```
void setToFive(int* x)
{
  if (x) {
    *x = 5;
  }
}
```

This function will take a pointer to an `int`, and then set that `int` to the value `5`. However, if the pointer passed is a null pointer, the value will not be set (otherwise there'll be undefined behaviour because you're derefencing a null pointer). Basically, passing a null pointer says "I don't care about this value so don't give it to me".

Now when you were initialising your pointers, you were doing:

```
double *estimate, *min = 0;
```

This only sets `min` to the null pointer. Since `estimate` is left uninitialized, you can't rely on its value being null. You need to provide an initialiser for each declarator:

```
double *estimate = 0, *min = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. But the code doesn't even cross the first check cout statement just after the main.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Make sure you do either `<< std::flush` or `<< std::endl` to flush your output buffer. Then give us the information you get from that.

Comment: yes, there was a small change. But I am not sure how and where u wanted me to implement that. I used it on the first check statement and that alone was printed, immediately followed by segmentation fault.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan You need to flush the buffer whenever you hope to see some output. Otherwise you can't guarantee that you'll get any output. So put `cout`s at various places in your code, making sure you flush them, and you'll find which line it is that causes your segfault. I have a feeling my latest edit will help you.

Comment: it did :). it was the initialization. Thanks a ton. could you actually explain me wat exactly is this segmentation fault?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Which bit fixed it? Changing `double* estimate` (and others) to `double estimate`?

Comment: none. changing the i,j=0 to i=0, j=0. i.e. freq=0, rows=0, cols=0

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sftrabbit. The problem was the initialization. instead of

```
    int freq,rows,cols=0;
```

The change was

```
    int freq=0,rows=0,cols=0;
```

this removed the segmentation fault. Thanks a lot for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in a Linux environment, you can use valgrind to find out exactly where the segmentation fault is happening. Just type valgrind before the name of the program, or the way you execute your program. For example, if you execute your program with the following command:

hello -print

issue the following command instead:

valgrind hello -print

I see you already solved this one, but this may be helpful in the future!